# SublimeText 3 sublimelinter-php

Tags: php, sublimetext

I cannot get sublimelint-php to work. I keep getting the error PHP not found.
These are the packages I have installed..

- Sublimelinter
- Sublimelinter-php

I have PHP installed under this directory C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/php.exe

In sublinter user-setting I have this as my path

```
   "paths": {
        "linux": [],
        "osx": [],
        "windows": [
              "C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/php.exe"
              ]
            }
```

I know there have been questions about this in the past but they are over a year old and none of them have helped me solve my issue..any help would be appreciated Thanks

Comment: On Windows, directories in a path are separated by backslashes (`\`) rather than forward slashes (`/`, which are used on Linux).

Answer (score 1):

Try it without `php.exe` in your path. I use the following setting on a windows machine and it works:

```
"paths": {
    "linux": [],
    "osx": [],
    "windows": [
        "D:/xampp/php/"
    ]
},
```

Even if windows uses backslashes as default path seperator make sure to use slashes as shown in the config above.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the path in the Sublime settings, why don't you try adding the `php.exe` executable to the Windows `PATH`?

You can do this by going to *Control Panel* > *System and Security* > *System*, clicking the *Advanced system settings* on the left-side panel, clicking *Environment variables*, double clicking the **PATH** entry in either of the lists and appending `;C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/` to its value.

Check that it works by opening a new Command window and typing `php -v`. SublimeLinter will pick up the executable from the PATH.